# Javascript / jQuery: replace (highlight) multiple user input words in autocomplete results

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, highlight

I have an jQuery autocomplete, where the user's search terms are highlighted in the search results.  Thanks to stackoverflow, I've gotten most of the way there and the terms are highlighted.

The problem comes when the second term is matched in the code that makes the first highlighted, so part of the HTML is highlighted.  E.g. if the search terms are 'word1 te' and the returned results contains:

"this is word1, I'm testing"

On the first iteration of my loop, it would become:
"this is `<span class='highlightedText'>`word1`</span>`, I'm testing"

On the second, it would not only highlight the 'te' in 'testing' but the 'te' in 'highlightedText'.  E.g.
"this is `<span class='highlight<span class='highlightedText'>`te`</span>`stingText'>word1`</span>`, I'm `<span class='highlightedText'>`te`</span>`sting"

Now, I could make the highlight text simpler by just making it bold, so instead of `<span class='highlightedText'>$1</span>`, it would be `<b>$1</b>` but what if my user inputs the letter 'b' on it's own, that tag would be tagged.

I could try to somehow exclude the letter 'b' from being highlighted but I'm hoping someone has a more elegant solution.

Phew! Hope that's clear.

Here's what I've got so far:

CSS:

```
.highlightedText {
    color: blue; font-weight:bold;
}
```

Regex found on stackoverflow:

```
    /**
    * http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net
    *   original by: booeyOH
    *   improved by: Ates Goral (http://magnetiq.com)
    *   improved by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
    *   bugfixed by: Onno Marsman
    *     example 1: preg_quote("$40");
    *     returns 1: '\$40'
    *     example 2: preg_quote("*RRRING* Hello?");
    *     returns 2: '\*RRRING\* Hello\?'
    *     example 3: preg_quote("\\.+*?[^]$(){}=!<>|:");
    *     returns 3: '\\\.\+\*\?\[\^\]\$\(\)\{\}\=\!\<\>\|\:' 
 */
function preg_quote( str ) {
    return (str+'').replace(/([\\\.\+\*\?\[\^\]\$\(\)\{\}\=\!\<\>\|\:])/g, "\\$1");
}
```

This is my code:

```
$("#search_member").autocomplete({
          minLength: 2,
          source: '/controller/module/action/term/' + $(this).val(),
          delay: '500',
          select: function (event, ui) {
                  // delete what they input
                  $(this).val('');
                  // the 'value' is a URL to navigate to
                  window.location.href = '/controller/module/index/mem_code/' + ui.item.mem_code;
                  // don't populate the autocomplete box
                  return false;
          }
    }).data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
        // search and replace matched search terms with bold version
        var highlighted = item.fullname;
        var termsString = this.term;
        var termsArr = termsString.split(' ');
        for (var i = 0; i < termsArr.length; i++) {
            var term = termsArr[i];
            highlighted = (highlighted+'')
                            .replace( 
                                new RegExp( "(" + preg_quote( term ) + ")" , 'gi' )
                                , "<span class='highlightedText'>$1</span>" 
            );
        }

        var listItem = '<a>' + highlighted + ' ' + 
                    item.type_code + '</a>' ;

        $("<li></li>").data("item.autocomplete", item)
                      .append(listItem)
                      .appendTo(ul);
        return;
    };

    // clear the search box if clicked
    $('.span_link').click(function() {
        $('#search_member').val('');
        $('#table_container').hide();
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually found the answer just before I submitted this but though I'd submit it anyway, in case it helped anyone else.

The problem was my for loop; didn't need it, just refined my reg-ex so that it replaces all the words in one go.  Here's the corrected '_renderItem' function:

```
.data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
    // search and replace matched search terms with bold version
    var highlighted = item.fullname;
    var termsString = this.term.trim();
    var words = termsString.split(' ').join('|');
    var regExp = new RegExp( "(" +  words + ")" , 'gi' );

     highlighted = (highlighted+'')
                     .replace( 
                         regExp
                         , "<span class='ui-state-highlight'>$1</span>" 
     );

    var listItem = '<a>' + highlighted + ' ' + 
                item.type_code + '</a>' ;

    $("<li></li>").data("item.autocomplete", item)
                  .append(listItem)
                  .appendTo(ul);
    return;
};
```

Don't need the preg_quote() function or the custom CSS snippet.